# What are some clever ways to serialize vectors of numbers efficiently?

Tags: java, serialization, binary, data-science

I'm doing some clustering/classification tasks and am looking into storing a sparse vector in a way that'll save as much space as possible.

The actual vector representation (i.e. CSR) doesn't matter much. For my purposes, I chose a format similar to what Mallet uses: pairs consisting of a feature id(long) and value(integer). They might look something like this:

```
6 0:2 5:3 21:7 31:1 33:9 41:5 42:2 60:6 77:6 88:1 92:3 104:1 117:4
8 5:9 19:2 21:6 31:1 33:1 42:7 77:4 104:1 117:2 140:3 141:2 154:6 
4 0:2 5:14 14:1 21:5 31:7 33:2 42:4 45:3 60:2 104:1 130:1 134:2 
5 0:5 5:2 21:5 28:1 31:1 33:4 42:4 60:3 71:1 77:3 117:1 130:1 134:3
11 0:6 5:9 15:2 18:1 21:5 28:4 31:4 32:1 33:2 42:6 49:3 56:1 60:3 94:1
1 0:4 5:4 21:5 28:1 33:5 40:1 42:4 60:4 77:3 150:1 154:2 157:1 161:1
3 0:6 5:11 21:10 28:2 31:2 33:6 42:10 60:1 77:4 85:1 97:1 134:3 141:2
```

Initially, I stored them in a text file in the exact format as shown above.
To my surprise, storing the information in a binary format (pairs of 8 byte long, 4 byte integer) actually seems larger, which might be because most values seem to be in a single digit range, which in turn takes exactly one byte to store in ASCI encoding.

What are some clever ways to save space (except for actual compression, which is undesirable for random access purposes) when dealing with numbers of variable size? I can't think of any "deterministic" serialization scheme that would use less space depending on the value and still be easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

first number stays same,

then features without spaces in order, each digit predicted by letter -> single digit a, two digits -> b ,etc..

`example:
 1 2 3 15 17 -> a123b1517
 1 3 101 -> a13c101,`

then values it the same manner:

example:

1 2 3 4 53 4 6 343 11 5 7 3-> a1234b53a46c343b11a573

your example:

`6 0:2 5:3 21:7 31:1 33:9 41:5 42:2 60:6 77:6 88:1 92:3 104:1 117:4
 8 5:9 19:2 21:6 31:1 33:1 42:7 77:4 104:1 117:2 140:3 141:2 154:6
 4 0:2 5:14 14:1 21:5 31:7 33:2 42:4 45:3 60:2 104:1 130:1 134:2`
...

->

`6a05b213133414260778892c104117|a2371952661314
 8a5b192131334277c104117140141154|a926117412326
 4a05b14213133424560c104130134|a2b14a1572432112`
...

since "|a" between features and values is often you can change it to one letter like z

Comment: Can you explain how this would be shorter?